# How do I create a *clean* AWS lambda function in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

###### Problem

When I run my lambda API locally with `sam local start-api`, I get the error `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}` for a request that is not supposed to require an authentication token.

###### Code

In my cloudformation template file I create a lambda function (see below) and an API Gateway for the API calls. As this setup will fail to run locally with `start-api` (thank you AWS?), I added the `Events` section you can see below.

```
MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: myapi
      Handler: lambda_handler.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.10
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      ...
      Events:
        Any:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            Path: '/myapi/*'
            Method: any
```

###### Steps to reproduce

- I run `sam build && sam local start-api` to run the API.
- I run `curl localhost:8080/myapi/ping`

  - 8080 is configured in samconfig
  - `/myapi/ping` is configure in the API Gateway and the lambda_handler itself.

Answer (score 0):

###### Problem

I don't understand why, but `Path: '/myapi/*'` seems to have been the problem.

###### How to fix

Using `Path: '/{proxy+}'` instead, fixed it.

**Warning**: If you use this in your template that you use for deployment, you will have the same setting on your server. This is probably not what you want.

*This is a community wiki. Whoever knows more, feel free to add details*